# Necessity for Osgood's Uniqueness Theorem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $\phi (z)$ be continuous and increasing function in the interval $[0,\infty)$, $\phi (0)=0, \phi (z) > 0 \, \forall z > 0$ with also:

$$\lim\limits_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0^{+}}\int\limits_{\epsilon}^{T} \dfrac{dz}{\phi(z)} =\infty \, \forall T > 0$$

Let $u(x)$ be a nonnegative continuous function in  $[0,a]$.Then the inequality 
$$
u(x) \le \int\limits_{0}^{x} \phi (u(t))dt \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\ \,  0 \le x \le a
$$
 implies that $u(x)\equiv 0$ in $[0,a]$

Comment: I don't see a question here, or any effort

Comment: if i can prove this lemma, i can prove Osgood's Uniqueness Theorem:). It's theorem 10.4 in An introduction to Odinary Differential Equations of Ravi P.Agarwal. There was a solution of this lemma in that book but i found it was incorrect, and I couldn't fix that solution.

Comment: It looked like you were just posting a homework problem and asking people to solve it for you, which people often do.  I suggest editing your question to show where it comes from, what you've tried, etc.